# HTML C# code not showing on webpage or page source

Tags: c#, html

I Have the simplest web page, a line of text. When I dotnet build & dotnet run, then launch the webpage, nothing is displayed despite the code being built fine. Any ideas?

My HTML code

```
@page
@model WebApp.Pages.ViewActors
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Web App</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>@Model.Heading</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

My C# class

```
namespace WebApp.Pages
{
    public class ViewActors : PageModel
    {
        public String Heading { get; set; }
        public void onGet()
        {
            Heading = "James Bond Actors";
        }
    }
}
```

So Model.heading = "James Bond Actors"
But the page source only displays,

```
<html lang="en"><head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Web App</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1></h1>

</body></html>
```

With nothing displayed between

```
<h1></h1>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

I've tried basic text and that displays but not the model.heading & viewed similar questions but no help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

onGet() should be OnGet() with a capital O.

Comment: Thanks so much. I must of glossed over that 100 times. What a silly little mistake to make, I should probably call it a day!